# panel refresh/load on button click in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do I make a panel refresh or load on button click in extjs?

I want to revert all changes in panel color to the default when I click the button go, next, or previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options : 
1. Get the reference to panel and delete it, then Ext.create('panle-class').Place this in place of destroyed panel.
2. Get the reference to panel change its styles to intended ones.